# Java - making an array using for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Is it possible in Java to make an array in a style similar to this, i have been searching for a while and haven't found anything.

```
int[] foo = {
    for(String arg:args)
        return Integer.parseInt(arg);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can do this instead :

```
int[] foo = new int[args.length];
for(int i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    foo[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
}
```

Comment: I wrote the same answer. Sorry I didn't know you already posted it. Maybe I was writing that time.

Comment: @Clutchy You're welcome (and it seems like you just got enough rep to vote :))

Comment: I was learning Python before and everything seems so long for me in Java :P

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly, but try this.

```
int[] foo = new int[args.length]; //Allocate the memory for foo first.
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i)
    foo[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
//One by one parse each element of the array.
```

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8, it can be done like this:

```
int[] foo = Stream.of(args).mapToInt(str -> Integer.parseInt(str)).toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Kind of... Since Java 8 we have streams which can simulate loop and allow us to do things like

```
int[] arr = Arrays.stream(args).mapToInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s)).toArray();
```

or its equivalent using [method references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

```
int[] arr = Arrays.stream(args).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] foo = new int[arg.length];
for (int i =0;i<args.length;i++) foo[i]=Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
```

Comment: Is this the only way?

Answer (score 1):

With array no, but you can do something similar with `List`:

```
final String args[] = {"123", "456", "789"};

List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>(){
    {
        for (String arg: args){
            add(Integer.parseInt(arg));
        }
    }
};

System.out.println(list); // [123, 456, 789]
```

With array you have to do the following:

```
int[] foo = new int[args.length];
for (int i = 0; i < foo.length; i ++) {
    foo[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
}
```